# disable download ashx json file

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have this rest api json web service for android application Handler1.ashx:

```
using JsonServices;
using JsonServices.Web;

namespace JSONWebAPI
{
    /// <summary>

    /// </summary>
    public class Handler1 : JsonHandler
    {
       public Handler1()
        {
            this.service.Name = "JSONWebAPI";
            this.service.Description = "JSON API for android appliation";
            InterfaceConfiguration IConfig = new InterfaceConfiguration("Service1", typeof(IServiceAPI), typeof(ServiceAPI));
            this.service.Interfaces.Add(IConfig);
        }

    }
}
```

The android app is going to this link: 
"mydomain.com/jsonWebAPI/Handler1.ashx" To retrieve details and to communicate with my c# code and sql server queries.

Now, if you add to the query string Handler1.ashx?android or ?csharp
All my json class will get download as a file and the user can see my code.

How can i prevent it ?
I want to secure this web service handler.

Thank you all.

Comment: Are you saying the browser is showing your C# code? Or some json data?

Comment: when someone goes directly to this link he get a file to download (save / save as) and the file that he will download contains the android or c# json class of my application

Comment: You need to put restrictions or filter on content/files the handler can serve or has access to serve. see [Handlers for dynamic content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx)